# Downloaded Ubuntu: how do I install it?

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu

I just downloaded Ubuntu, to replace Windows 10, but cannot find how to install it, by running the usual .exe file (or its equivalent on Linux) needed to install a program. Looks also it was downloaded ... on my DVD drive, which seems odd, as normally, if there is no DVD, there is nothing on that drive.

Sorry if this seems a stupid question, I tried to find elsewhere before asking it.

Comment: @MBBNF check out this post  http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can't install it from windows, it's not a little software, it's a system, the link between hardware and software.
You must load the dvd at the startup : boot on the dvd. You use all the drive, or, before, reduce the drive (see this page : http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-shrink-windows-10-to-make-space.html) and use only a part of the drive for windows, the other part for linux. So you keep the old functionnal system, and you can do your first steps on ubuntu. After installation, at each start, you will have the choice. After, the possibility is kept to destroy windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the internet.
2. Make a bootable DVD or USB of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
3. Put it in appropriate drive/slot.
4. Switch on your computer having preinstalled Windows.
5. Select the boot option for the DVD/ USB of Ubuntu OS.
6. Go for try out UBUNTU. Once booted, familiarise yourself. Explore and try out different aspects of Ubuntu.
7. When you are satisfied and have become more curious, then on the DASH press 'Install Ubuntu'. Sit back and relax.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Linux is **not** software, or a program, it's a whole OS. You can't install it while booted to Windows. It does not have an executable file to install it. You have to install it in your boot-up menu.

If you want your answer, click here: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu?lq=1)